# Sending mails through cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I was using the following code snippet to send mails, but moving to another host messed everything up:

```
    public function forgetpwd(){    
//code omitted
    if($this->User->saveField('token_hash',$fu['User']['token_hash'] )){

                            //============Email================//
                            /* SMTP Options */
                            $this->Email->smtpOptions = array(
                                    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',                             
                                    'port'=>'465',
                                    'transport' => 'Smtp',
                                    'username'=>'email@gmail.com',
                                    'password'=>'secret',
                                    'tls' => true
                            );
                            $this->Email->template = 'resetpw';
                            $this->Email->from    = 'noreply@email.com';
                            $this->Email->to      = $fu['User']['name'].'<'.$fu['User']['email'].'>';
                            $this->Email->subject = __('Recover your password');
                            $this->Email->sendAs = 'both';

                            $this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';
                            $this->set('ms', $ms);
                            $this->Email->send();
                            $this->set('smtp_errors', $this->Email->smtpError);
                            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Check your email to recover your password'));
}

                            //============EndEmail=============//
```

So there is this view *forgetpwd.ctp* where user is asked to enter his/her email address, and when trying to send the email, I am given the two following errors:

```
Error: The view for UsersController::forgetpwd() was not found.

Error: Confirm you have created the file: /home/public_html/development/app/View/Emails/text/resetpw.ctp
```

I am sure that the *resetpw.ctp* exists in the right place.

I have edited the email config and tried to adopt the 2.3 cakePHP way, and this is what I have ended up with:

```
            if($this->User->saveField('token_hash',$fu['User']['token_hash'] )){

                App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

                $Email = new CakeEmail('default');

                $Email->to($fu['User']['email'])
                        ->subject('Reset your password')
                        ->message($key)
                        ->send();

                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Check your mail to reset your password'));

                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'reset'));
```

But now, when I try to send an email, I get the following error:

```
Call to a member function send() on a non-object
```

Comment: The path `/home/public_html/development/` sounds very much like a local debug path? Are you sure that it's correct? Also try clearing your cache files (everything under `app/tmp/cache`), while preserving the directory structure of the cache folder.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
```

to

```
'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
```

also put your config info in email.php inside App/Config/ as referenced here:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#configuration

Comment: Thanks for helping, I have made an edit, but now the Email class seems not to be loaded.
I have updated the question with the code snippets.